# Docker: nginx container at the same level of other containers - is it sufficient?

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm building 3 docker containers at the same level inside a network: Nginx, my front app and my api. Nginx forwards requests to other containers.

Should other containers also contain nginx servers or is it fine with only one Nginx outside the container?

For example, compression is activated in my nginx container, but there is no nginx configured in my api container. Does it slow things down inside the api container?

A request follows the below flow:

```
Web user -> Nginx container -> api container -> API processing -> nginx container -> web user
```

Should it be:

```
Web user -> Nginx container -> api container -> Nginx in api container -> API processing ->  Nginx in api container -> Nginx container -> web user
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure you do not need a second instance of nginx inside the other containers. This is the reason why Dokcker is here; **to isolate things**. Your question is a bit tricky, it all depends on how your API implementation is (how efficient it is and how good it is written to handle the requests forwarded by nginx).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it definitely makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Docker way is one main process per container. You do not need to put nginx inside each container with your app.

I think you could use one nginx container as front service.